# Can the perceptron classifier achieve perfect accuracy, on any data set?

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I was thinking. Since any data can become linearly seprabale through kernel methods, meaning there is a dimension where this data is linearly seprable, so feed this processed data set into the perceptron algorithm and then it might get to 100 percent accuracy.

Am I correct?

Comment: **if** you can find the right kernel!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem#Arbitrary-width_case

Comment: You can also achieve 100% accuracy on the training data with the "look up the answer in the training data" model.  100% accuracy is a strawman - the task in any modeling scenario is to develop a model that *generalizes to unseen data*.  It is trivial to create models with 100% accuracy that generalize terribly.  You can "approximate" unseen data by leaving out some of your training data for validation, but even this is a strawman.  Think carefully about what sort of data you'll be applying your model to vs what you have to train on.

Comment: @user253751 it's not hard.  Sigmoid works for the universal approximation theorem, but there are many others.

Comment: @Him you're thinking of multi-layer perceptrons

Comment: @user253751 is OP not?  It's not super clear.

Comment: @Him it repeatedly says perceptron and does not mention multiple layers, so the assumption is that it's a perceptron, and not a multi-layer perceptron

Answer (score 1):

The use of a nonlinear kernel never gives any guarantees to make any data set linearly separable in the higher dimensional feature space. Kernels are used to map the data from input space onto a higher dimensional space, in which a hyperplane will be better at separating the data (but no guarantee for linear separable higher dimensional mapped data). That is why we can not be sure that perceptron algorithm will work correctly on higher dimensional mapped dataset or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Yes:  Given a large enough perceptron (with enough layers and enough neurons), you can achieve 100% accuracy on the training set: i.e., you can construct a perceptron that perfectly fits everything in the training set.

No, not necessarily: Depending on the learning task, you might not be able to achieve 100% accuracy on the test set, no matter how large your perceptron is and no matter what your kernel is.

Comment: Over-fitting is always an option.